# Spawn containers on ACI using @azure/arm-containerinstance

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-container-instances

I am working on processing data microservice. I have this microservice dockerized and now I want to deploy it. To achieve it, I am trying to manage containers in Azure Container Instances using Azure Function written in node.js.

The first thing I wanted to test is spawning containers within a group. My idea was:

```
const oldConfig = await client.containerGroups.get(
    'resourceGroup',
    'resourceName'
);

const response = await client.containerGroups.createOrUpdate(
  'resourceGroup',
  'resourceName',
  {
    osType: oldConfig.osType,
    containers: [
      ...oldConfig.containers,
      {
        name: 'test',
        image: 'hello-world',
        resources: {
          requests: {
            memoryInGB: 1,
            cpu: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

I've added osType, because docs and interface says it's required, but when I do this I receive error 'to update osType you need to remove and create group containers". When I remove osType, request is successful, but ACI does not change. I cannot recreate whole group upon every new container, because I want them to process jobs and terminate by themselves.

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all the properties are supported to update. See the details below:

> Not all container group properties can be updated. For example, to
> change the restart policy of a container, you must first delete the
> container group, then create it again.
>
> Changes to these properties require container group deletion prior to
> redeployment:
>
> OS type CPU, memory, or GPU resources Restart policy Network profile

So the container group will not change after you update the `osType`. You need to delete the container group and create it with the changes. Get more details about the [Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update).

Comment: OK, so I suppose it's impossible to spawn / terminate containers within a single container groups. Does it mean that for every task I have to create a new ACI? It is really weird for me.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak If you need to change the properties not support every time, then you need to recreate the ACI every time.

Comment: Let's for example take a CI/CD jobs. Each job is new container. I've seen that ACI is recommended for this type of tasks. But I do not really understand why, because I would need to create / remove ACI for each CI/CD job. ACI is allowing to create multiple containers and in the same time it requires to start / stop them all at once. It does not make sense to me.

Comment: I would expect such strategy to be possible:
I create an ACI ->
I write a function that manages this ACI ->
Function receives new task ->
Function creates new container on ACI and delegates this task ->
When task is done, container o ACI terminates...
and so on, but it seems impossible.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak Maybe the Jenkins is a possible tool. You can take a try with the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/azure-container-instances-as-jenkins-build-agent).

Comment: Not really helpful tutorial I would say, it does not describe anything about ACI and I do not care about Jenkins. It still does not answer whether I am allowed to change containers inside ACI or not. Although looks like ACI is far less useful than I thought, so I will just accept your answer and look into other possible solutions of my case.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak Yes, ACI is still not fully functional as we think. In my opinion, it's just a light and quick-start service. The full controllable service is AKS or the VM directly.